# Gulp watch not triggering

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I am working on a project that uses gulp to concatenate compiled vue assets with other javascript assets.

When running `gulp`, all runs successfully.

However, now I need to add a watcher on the compiled vue file as show below.

```
gulp.task('watch', ['scripts'], function() {
    gulp.watch('js/vue/compiled.js', { ignoreInitial: false });
});
```

While the watcher process seems to kickoff, it does not update when the compiled.js file gets updated. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually how I write **gulp tasks** is like this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/vue/compiled.js', ['scripts'], { ignoreInitial: false });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing the gulp function to execute in gulp.task rather place it in gulp.watch. Something like this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/vue/compiled.js', ['scripts'], { ignoreInitial: false });
});
```